# My array formula does not seem to be working, Although I think I wrote it correctly

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

=ARRAYFORMULA({
IFERROR(
FILTER({Plan A!A5:A, Plan A!B5:B, Plan A!C5:C, Plan A!D5:D, Plan A!F5:F, Plan A!K5:K, Plan A!Z5:Z, Plan A!Y5:Y}, (Plan A!K5:K <> Plan A!F5:F) * (Plan A!J5:J <> "Yes"))
),
IFERROR(
FILTER({'Plan B'!A5:A, 'Plan B'!B5:B, 'Plan B'!C5:C, 'Plan B'!D5:D, 'Plan B'!F5:F, 'Plan B'!K5:K, 'Plan B'!Z5:Z, 'Plan B'!Y5:Y}, ('Plan B'!K5:K <> 'Plan B'!F5:F) * ('Plan B'!J5:J <> "Yes")))
})

I am getting this error: Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 5. Actual: 1.

Comment: you don't have single quotes around all the tab names.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror({FILTER({'Plan A'!A5:A, 'Plan A'!B5:B, 'Plan A'!C5:C, 'Plan A'!D5:D, 'Plan A'!F5:F, 'Plan A'!K5:K, 'Plan A'!Z5:Z, 'Plan A'!Y5:Y}, ('Plan A'!K5:K <> 'Plan A'!F5:F) * ('Plan A'!J5:J <> "Yes")) , FILTER({'Plan B'!A5:A, 'Plan B'!B5:B, 'Plan B'!C5:C, 'Plan B'!D5:D, 'Plan B'!F5:F, 'Plan B'!K5:K, 'Plan B'!Z5:Z, 'Plan B'!Y5:Y}, ('Plan B'!K5:K <> 'Plan B'!F5:F) * ('Plan B'!J5:J <> "Yes")) }))
```